# Footnote inside tabularx inside minipage

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, tabularx, minipage

The footnote from inside the `tabularx` environment dose not get displayed when the `hyperref` package is loaded. The `tabular` environment on the other hand works like expected in both cases. 
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X c  }
            A1\footnote{footnoteX} & B1  \\
            A2 & B2  \\ 
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}      

    \begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ c c  }
            A1\footnote{footnote} & B1  \\
            A2& B2  \\  
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}      
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X c  }
            \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}
            A1\footnotemark & B1  \\
            A2 & B2  \\ 
        \end{tabularx}
        \footnotetext[1]{footnoteX}%sadly you have to specify the number in this case
    \end{minipage}      

    \begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ c c  }
            A1\footnote{footnote} & B1  \\
            A2& B2  \\  
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}      
\end{document}
```